# Callback окончания записи файла после ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, камера, photo

Приложение запускает камеру, получает оттуда изображение и запускает `cropIntent` (в `onActivityResult`); Камеру использую системную:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

Изображение сохраняю через `Fileprovider`

```
photoOutput = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, packageName + ".fileprovider", file);
```

`photoIntent` передает путь из `fileprovider` библиотеке `com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper`

То есть мой код находится между нативным кодом андроида и кодом библиотеки. 
Обнаружил, что системный код возвращает управление моему в `onActivityResult`, но фотографию пишет в файл в отдельном потоке. А следовательно на медленных девайсах `cropIntent` вызывается раньше, чем изображение записано в файл. Как следствие в активити кроппера я не получаю свое изображение. Есть вариант запускать код с задержкой, например 200-300 мс (чтобы изображение успело записаться), но это не гарантирует того, что изображение будет за это время записано в файл, а значит работать будет через раз (+ некрасивый ui). Идеальным решением было бы повесить `Callback` на окончание записи файла и запускать `cropIntent` по команде. Можно ли как то отловить этот момент?

Брать  `Bitmap` из `data.getData()` не подойдет, потому что туда приходит слишком маленькое изображение (с разрешением пару сотен пикселов)

Comment: Попробуйте решение [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36099490/3069565). То есть не создавать файл самостоятельно а передать только имя. `file = new File("path/name.jpg")`

Comment: Потребность в решении отпала, решил другим путем. Проблема была в том, что несмотря на то, что ImageCropper подгружает изображение асинхронно стейт он не сохраняет. В результате из-за поворотов активити с фото вертелась активити кроппера (причины мне пока не понятны, не спрашивайте :) ). В результате я выдернул кроппер в проект и сделал обработку сохранения стейта. И все заработало, как часы

Comment: @eugeneek, да, я именно так и делал изначально. Дело в том, что возникает гонка, и пока процесс сохранения фото пишет данные в этот  path, не асинхронная ImageView не может его отобразить (потому что в тот момент, когда изображение должно просетиться - оно еще не готово)

Comment: Если я, конечно, правильно понимаю процесс обработки классом ImageView некоего Uri

Comment: Рад, что проблема решилась. Просто мне кажется странным, что камера закрывает своё активити и возвращает результат не дождавшись завершения асинхронной записи фото в файл...